# porting numpy fromfile to python3 when reading from standard input

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I'm porting some code to Python 3 and stumbled upon an invocation of `numpy.fromfile(src)` which works just fine when `src` is a handle of a real file but fails when `src` is `sys.stdin`. I boiled down the issue to the following two commands that will let you see how the problem only exists in Python 3 but not in Python 2:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 | python -c 'import numpy,sys; print(numpy.fromfile(sys.stdin, dtype=int, sep=" "))'
[1 2 3]
$ echo 1 2 3 | python3 -c 'import numpy,sys; print(numpy.fromfile(sys.stdin, dtype=int, sep=" "))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: obtaining file position failed
```

When I look at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/records.py` then it seems that even in the Python2 version of numpy it says for fromfile:

> The file object must support random access (i.e. it must have tell and seek methods).

So I guess the fact that the above works with Python2 was never meant to be supported. Still the code I want to port to Python3 relied on this functionality.

I tried reading `sys.stdin` into an `io.BytesIO` but this will error out with `io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno`.

In my hopes that others also stumbled across this problem, I wanted to ask for an easy drop-in replacement of `numpy.fromfile()` which allows reading from stdin even on Python3. Certainly other projects already had to implement a solution to this? I wasn't able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading bytes from `stdin` like this:

```
data = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
```

And then using `numpy.frombuffer` to read it. (You should also provide the datatype)

```
arr = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.float)
```

If you are reading text data, you can do this:

```
data = sys.stdin.read()
arr = numpy.fromstring(data, sep=" ")
```

When you don't provide `sep` it acts in some legacy mode.